# Unique product types filtering in array per customer

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I'm trying to do it in normal way in php without bunch of foreach's.

I have array like this:

```
$data['martin'] = [100 => 'product 1', 200 => 'product 2', 300 => 'product 3']
$data['taylor'] = [200 => 'product 2', 300 => 'product 3']
$data['steven'] = [100 => 'product 1', 300 => 'product 3']
```

I need to show **UNIQUE** product names that and IF each customer has it

**Expected result: product 3**

(product 3 is shown because all of them have product 3)

Comment: might be able to use array_intersect() - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php along with array_diff() - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use usual [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect) function:

```php
$result = array_intersect($data['martin'], $data['taylor'], $data['steven']);
```

The result will be:

```
array(300 => "product 3")
```